# How do I compile JonBot-NG?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've tried for few hours.. and failed. i can't seem to get it to work. ( in NetBeans)

I've added libraries that creator pointed out, source and nbproject - I get errors.

Can someone tell me what to do step by step? Thank you in advance.

**LINK TO GITHUB:** https://github.com/lucidexploration/JonBot-NG

Comment: We need to know what you tried and which errors you got.

Comment: So i've tried adding it - I downloaded the zip from github then I created new project in netbeams (selected as  just Java) then I went to "files" tab and dragged and dropped down src folder from zip i downloaded from GitHub then nbproject and the rest. I've got an JAVADOC error.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps which worked for me.

**1.** In NetBeans

File > New Project > Java > Java Application >
Project Name: JonBot-NG
untick Create Main Class
> Finish

**2.** Unzip JonBot-NG-master.zip file

**3.** Copy contents of the src folder into NetBeans/JonBot-NG/Source Packages

**4.** Download JNA library from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/raw/master/dist/jna.jar

Right click the JonBot-NG project in NetBeans > Properties > Libraries > Compile tab > Add JAR/Folder > select jna.jar > OK

**5.** Download JIntelliType from https://github.com/lucidexploration/JonBot-NG

Extract the file

Right click the JonBot-NG project in NetBeans > Properties > Libraries > Compile tab > Add JAR/Folder > select jintellitype-1.3.9/jintellitype-1.3.9.jar > OK

**6.** Download DS Explorer from https://dsexplorer.googlecode.com/files/dsExplorer-v0.6.jar

Right click the JonBot-NG project in NetBeans > Properties > Libraries > Compile tab > Add JAR/Folder > select dsExplorer-v0.6.jar > OK

**7.** Right click the JonBot-NG project in NetBeans > Run > OK